# Ill-conditioned covariance matrices in EM

Tags: machine-learning, covariance, covariance-matrix, linear-algebra

I am currently working with the Expectation-Maximization algorithm. I have some pre-clustered sets of 3D points and am trying to run the algorithm. However I've seen that most of my covariance matrices have a very large condition number so things break down very fast.  I have checked about preconditioning matrices and saw two suggestions to some other question. The first was to multiply by $P^{-1}$ with $P = L*L^t$ and $L$ being obtained from an LU decomposition. The second was to add a small number to the diagonal. However none of these approaches worked. Is there any way to precondition these matrices so as to remove the numeric issues? Or any transformation I can use to reduce the condition number?

Update

I have tried some of the solutions offered however they have not really solved the issue. This is because my covariance matrix is 3x3 while the samples per cluster can take any value. What stops working is the calculation of the responsibilities for each Gaussian Mixture Model so solutions like using $x-\mu$\ $cov$ don't really work. Any other suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Precondition and/or Tikhonov regularisation are pretty much our only chances. Having said that, what exactly do you solve? What is the step that "breaks down"? For example almost certainly you shouldn't invert any matrices. Do you matrices have a particular (block) structure?

Comment: I am trying to cluster points in three dimensions. There is indeed and inversion of the matrices, this ends throwing NaNs or Infs. They have no particular block structure. They are 3x3 symmetric. Other than that I have found no patterns. I Consulted with another friend and he suggested that I use higher order statistics instead of relying on covariance. Could this help?

Comment: In which part do you use these matrices? If you use these to solve a system (ie. something like $A^{-1} b$) then you do not need to invert these matrices. You can use other decompositions on them.

Comment: Since I am using EM for a Gaussian mixture model. When I calculate the "responsibility" of each cluster I have $R_i = K*e^{-0.5*(x_i-\mu_i)*\sigma^{-1}*(x_i-\mu_i)^t}*\pi_i$. There I have the matrix inversion and I don't think I can actually get rid of that. Where $\mu_i$ is the mean of cluster i and $\sigma$ is the covariance matrix of cluster i.

Comment: You do not need to invert that terms; you simply solve a linear system. I do not know what language you use but for instance in MATLAB and R you should write : `(x-m)\sigma` and `solve(x-m,sigma)` respectively instead of using `inv(sigma)` or `solve(sigma)`.

Comment: The issue is that the number of elements contained in x can vary greatly from say only two points in one cluster to over 40. And that is why the $(x-m)\sigma$ is not really working. I was using $\sigma\eye(3)$ in Matlab. But it still gives those high condition numbers.

Comment: OK, go ahead and include this information in your original post. Try to be specific about what you do and exactly what you compute, dimensions of the matrices involved and so forth.

Comment: In addition to the items already mentioned, there is another lever you might be able to employ, i.e., higher precision numerical calculations, which will let you "get away with" a larger condition number.  There are multiple precision add-ons for MATLAB.  Unfortunately, calculations will be much slower, however you might be able to employ higher precision calculations only where they are really needed.